# How to trigger the native select box using SelectBoxIt jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used SelectBoxIt plugin to display the select boxes in my application.

I have two select boxes, if I change the value in first select box, another should automatically update (it should trigger automatically).

For both select boxes values are passing dynamically, I used below code

```
$('.ember-select').selectBoxIt({
            theme: "default",
            autoWidth: false,
            triggerChangeCombined: true
        });
```

i used

```
$('.ember-select').selectBoxIt({
            native: true
        });
```

it will trigger but the slectbox other properties like "theme","autoWidth" are not rendering.

Comment: A fiddle will be more helpful for us to solve!!

Comment: hai Guruprasad Rao http://jsfiddle.net/reimeister/3LdWg/ ,please refer this link.

Comment: Your fiddle does not contain another select box??

Comment: Will values in both the selectbox remains same or they are different??

Comment: both the values are different

Comment: so automatic updation will be based on what criteria on other select box??

Comment: Please update your question with relevant details and options and what you want exactly!!

Comment: My application is like fleet management, in first select box i have four options 1. vehilces 2. geofence 3. fleet 4. trailers , if i select vehicle in first selectBox ,second selectbox should automatically update all vehicles, suppose if i select geofence in first selectbox in second it should update only geofence vehilces .

Comment: Posted the answer!! try it once and let me know!!

Comment: Anytime!! Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok You can check this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/okLapc35/2/)** and code below:

Here is your sample **HTML**

```
<div class='formArea'>
    <label>Mode:</label><br/>
    <select id="modes" name="modes">
        <option disabled selected>
            -- Choose a Mode --
         </option>
         <option>Vehicle</option>
         <option>Fleet</option>
         <option>Trailers</option>
     </select><br/>
    <label>Options:</label><br/>
    <select id="optionss" name="optionss">
        <option disabled selected>
            -- Options --
        </option>

     </select><br/>
</div>
```

Below is your **JS:**

```
var vehicles = ['Vehicle 1', 'Vehicle 2', 'Vehicle 3', 'Vehicle 4', 'Vehicle 5']; //add all your vehicle options here
var fleet = ['fleet 1', 'fleet 2', 'fleet 3', 'fleet 4', 'fleet 5']; //add all your fleet options here
var trailers = ['trailer 1', 'trailer 2', 'trailer 3', 'trailer 4', 'trailer 5']; //add all your trailers options here

var optionss =  [{name: "Vehicles", clubs: vehicles},
                 {name: "Fleet", clubs: fleet},
                 {name: "Trailers", clubs: trailers}
                ];


$(function() {
    var selectedmode = $('#modes option:selected').text()
    var optionmenu = $('#optionss');
    for (var i = 0; i < optionss.length; i++) {
         if (selectedmode === optionss[i].name) {
              $.each(optionss, function(val, obj) {
                  optionmenu.append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(obj.clubs));
              });
         }
    }
});

$('#modes').on('change',function(){
    var mode=$(this).find(":selected").text();
    $('#optionss').find('option').remove();
    switch(mode)
    {
        case 'Vehicles':
            $.each(vehicles, function(key, value) {   
                    $('#optionss')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .text(value)); 
            });
            break;

        case 'Fleet':
            $.each(fleet, function(key, value) {   
                    $('#optionss')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .text(value)); 
            });
            break;
        case 'Trailers':
            $.each(trailers, function(key, value) {   
                    $('#optionss')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .text(value)); 
            });
            break;
        default:break;        
      }
});
```